# android webview word break prolems

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

i have been found the problem days, but i could't get it.

the view works fine in desktop chrome

but it will auto break the word with the situation that width is enough to show.

e.g.

```
okay let's do 
it.
```

i don't set any width, word-break, word-wrap, white-space ...

if the width value set to 100%, it works fine,

but i need it grow the width itself because there is background color, if width:100%, the background color will fullfill whole div.

```
<div class="bubble">
    <p>okay, let' do it</p>
</div>
```

edit:

i am using cordova, and i change it to warp_content, not work

```
public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    webView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Show us your xml code (`Webview`) . Using `wrap-content` on `WebView` will resolve it

Comment: i am using cordova, but i am looking for the setting

Comment: i had changed it, but it didn't work. @hrskrs